# Parameterize S3 URI in LOAD DATA FROM S3 SQL statement (Aurora MySQL)

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

In our team, we want to import multiple tables from an S3 bucket into an Aurora 8 (MySQL) database using SQL. Yet, the `LOAD DATA FROM S3` statement seems only to support literal URI strings, not string expressions. How can we avoid specifying the same S3 bucket URI multiple times?

Comment: If you load more than one table, you must prepare a new `LOAD DATA` query anyway, because the table name is an identifier, and thus also cannot be a parameter. I suggest you write code in your application to prepare a new query for each table. Is this a problem?

Comment: @Bill Karwin Thank you for looking into this. Yes, this is a problem since the scripts are not embedded into an application. These are the kind of one-off SQL scripts that you run manually (once) to migrate data from A to B.

Comment: You will need to write a distinct `LOAD DATA` command in your script for each table. I still don't understand why this is a problem. Scripts can contain more than one statement.

Comment: @BillKarwin the problem is that the S3 URI is configuration information. Someone will need to run the script on multiple Aurora instances. On that occasion, it is easier when one needs to exchange the URI string only at one place. The goal is to minimize the risk of errors.